# c++ is it worth preprocessor optimization for for loops while i < 1

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm writing some code to take high precision timings of a function call

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
>     beginTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
>
>     CallFunc(functionPtr, otherParamaters ...); // inline function call to do the timed function
>
>     endTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
>     elapsedTime = duration_cast<duration<double>>(endTime - beginTime);
>     timings.push_back(elapsedTime.count());
> }
> ```

However some of the functions I'm timing run so fast the clock can't pick them up, it ends up just writing a load of `0`s

I Had the idea to do several repetitions of the function call per timing, to try to get a numerical time I could then divide down past the resolution of the clock, but I don't want to penalize the accuracy of the timing for functions that don't need these repetitions

My solution was to use preprocessor `#if`s

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
>     beginTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
>
> #if repetitions > 1
>     for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
> #endif 
>         CallFunc(functionPtr, otherParamaters ...); // inline function call to do the timed function
> #if repetitions > 1
>     }
> #endif    
>     endTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
>     elapsedTime = duration_cast<duration<double>>(endTime - beginTime);
>     timings.push_back(elapsedTime.count());
> }
> ```

My question is, is this kind of optimization silly? Is the compiler likely to do this for me anyway?

EDIT: repetitions is a `const int`

Comment: Is repititions a compile time constant? If yes, it's probably not necessary. The compiler can unroll the loop itself.

Comment: Welcome to code review where we review working code from one of your projects and provide suggestions on how to improve your code. As pointed out in the comment by @MikaelH there is some code here that is missing that is necessary, and that prevents us from doing a good review. This makes the question off-topic for code review. I would suggest first searching stackoverflow.com for an answer to your question, if an answer doesn't doesn't exist then ask the question on stackoverflow, but make sure to follow their [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Suggestion, this is not a compile time decision, I would have an if statement based on a first test of elapsed time, if elapsed time is zero, do it in a loop, if elapsed time is not zero you have enough resolution to do it the other way. When I had a job where CPU processor time mattered we measured performance using loops of basic instructions in operations over a million times.

Comment: @Jake: Use https://github.com/google/benchmark . Don't try to write microbenchmarking code on your own; your results won't mean anything.

Answer (score 2):

Notational suggestion: *if* insisting on a bracketed controlled statement, favour

```
#if 0 < repetitions
# if 1 < repetitions
    for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
# endif
    {
        CallFunc(functionPtr, otherParamaters …); // inline call to timed function
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Why not simply `#if repetitions != 1`? That would make the other `#if` redundant.

Comment: @RolandIllig it is about *explicit* (my preference) vs. *implicit*, covered by your suggestion. Using just `repetitions > 1` to control the visibility gets the statement executed once for `repetitions` 0 - makes me icky. That is handled by the original `for` construct pre-processor controlled as per your suggestion - I'd feel pressed to leave a code comment. And think it better to code the blatantly obvious way instead of explaining.